# tomcat upgrade issue in fedora commons

Tags: tomcat, solr, fedora-commons

I have recently upgraded tomcat to latest version 6.0.37 in Fedora Commons 3.4. Since then, **automatic updates to Solr are not working when a new object is ingested in Fedora**. I am not sure if GSearch is broken because of the upgraded tomcat. With this issue, I always have to manually visit the REST page and then hit "updateIndex". Earlier it used to work automatically, when I ingested the product, it used to get indexed in Solr automatically. I couldn't find anything useful in the logs.

Could you please let me know **if there are any steps that should be followed to upgrade tomcat that originally came with Fedora Commons 3.4?**

All I did for upgrading tomcat in Fedora folder was - I downloaded latest tomcat version 6.0.37 and then copied its content to the old tomcat folder in Fedora folder. Restarted tomcat. I use Windows OS. Please let me know if I missed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While installation of fedora `fcrepo-installer-3.x.x.jar` you can select `existingTomcat` instead of `included` when it asks for tomcat. You can then provide the path of your another tomcat server directory.

> Servlet engine
>   Which servlet engine will Fedora be running in?
>   Enter 'included' to use the bundled Tomcat 6.0.20 server.
>   To use your own, existing installation of Tomcat, enter 'existingTomcat'.
>   Enter 'other' to use a different servlet container.
>
> Options : included, existingTomcat, other
>
> Enter a value [default is included] ==> **existingTomcat**
>
> Tomcat home directory
>   Please provide the full path to your existing Tomcat installation, or
>   the path where you plan to install the bundled Tomcat.
>
> Enter a value  [default somedirectory] ==>  **yourdirectory**

This way you can auto-configure fedora with your custom tomcat that you upgraded.